# Skrollr not working on mobile?

Tags: javascript, skrollr

I can't figure for the life of me why skrollr is not working on mobile.

My `skrollr-body` id is below all elements that are fixed and I've initialized skrollr and menu, and there isn't anything else in the docs that explain why this isn't working...

Works in desktop, not in mobile...Any suggestions?

standard initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var s;
  s = skrollr.init({
    forceHeight: false
  });
  skrollr.menu.init(s);

  //some other document ready code...
});
```

html pseudo code

```
//body is 100% height
<body>
//this link is a fixed menu that only shows up after the person has scrolled 100% height
    <a href="#third" class="menu" data-0="opacity:0;" data-100p="opacity:1" data-menu-top="200p"> 
    NEXT PROJECT</a>

// skrollr-body is 100% height and width, float left
    <div id="skrollr-body">

        //top is 100% height and width,overflow hidden and position absolute
        <div id="top">
        </div>  

        //second is 100% height and weight, position absolute and top is 100% 
        // (this makes 'second' show up immediately after the 'top' page.
        <div id="second">
        </div>

        //third is 100% height and weight, position absolute and top is 200%, 
        // making it show up exactly after the 'second' div
        <div id="third">
        </div>
   </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What is your mobile SO version?

Comment: @avrilalejandro I am using samsung galaxy nexus android 4.3 chrome browser version 37. Skrollr is the most recent 0.6.26

Comment: activation requires javascript. you have it enabled? . [see activate](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=en)

Comment: @avrilalejandro just checked, it was already enabled...I notice in my remote debugging when I try typing in `skrollr.menu.init(s)` in the console it comes up undefined but `skrollr.init()` returns a skrollr instance...Typing `skrollr.menu` in the console also indicates that it recognizes skrollr menu as an object with an `init` and a `click` function but initializing comes up undefined...

Comment: [see javascript mobile support](http://mobilehtml5.org).The problem may not support some instances

Comment: @avrilalejandro I don't understand what you are referring to by 'the problem may not support some instances' and there is javascript support for skrollr in mobile. Many people are able to use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61519/discussion-between-chowza-and-avril-alejandro).